# SQL Server - Company Information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a company directory and need some help with the SQL Server database.

The tables I have are `Employees`, `Departments`, `Equipment`, `Phonenumber`

The table `Employees`, `Department`, `Equipment` can have phone number (many phone numbers)

It's like this, `Employees` can have phone numbes and equipment

`Departments` can have many phone numbers and many equipment

`Equipment` can have many phone numbers

Hope for some help

Comment: Seems like he needs CREATE TABLE sql's. I suggest you try first and then ask for help.

Comment: what is your solution so for. you need study relationship concepts

Comment: Do you really want to name them tables "Employess", "Departments", "Equicpment" and "Phonenumber"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you didn't point out the desired correlations as you actually have in mind. And I do not question the sense behind it. But to emphasize what I got out of your explanations, I give a short summary:

- Employees may have one phone number and one equipment.
- Departments may have many phone numbers and many equipments.
- Equipments may have many phone numbers.

Here you go with the corresponding table definitions (an excerpt):

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  equipment_id INT NOT NULL,
  phone_number_id INT NOT NULL,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_equipment_id) REFERENCES Equipment (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_phone_number_id) REFERENCES PhoneNumber (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Department (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE Equipment (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE DepartmentEquipment (
  department_id INT NOT NULL,
  equipment_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (department_equipment_department_id) REFERENCES Department (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (department_equipment_equipment_id) REFERENCES Equipment (id)
)

CREATE TABLE DepartmentPhoneNumber (
  department_id INT NOT NULL,
  phone_number_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (department_phone_number_department_id) REFERENCES Department (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (department_phone_number_phone_number_id) REFERENCES PhoneNumber (id)
)

CREATE TABLE EquipmentPhoneNumber (
  equipment_id INT NOT NULL,
  phone_number_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (equipment_phone_number_equipment_id) REFERENCES Equipment (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (equipment_phone_number_phone_number_id) REFERENCES PhoneNumber (id)
)
```